# Should "bdd" and "behaviour-driven-design" tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should [bdd](/questions/tagged/bdd) and [behaviour-driven-design](/questions/tagged/behaviour-driven-design) tags be merged?

I think so. I would like to hear your opinion.

Comment: Well… they are kind of the same thing… Yes.

Comment: @bjb568: Thank you for your comment. Let's wait to see what the moderators say.

Comment: Well... ***we are*** the moderators. Stack Exchange is community moderated. The diamond moderators are there to deal with exceptional situations we can't handle ourselves, not to make the decisions for us.

Comment: You are right. What should be the next step?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there are only 7 questions in the [behaviour-driven-design](/questions/tagged/behaviour-driven-design) tag, and 5 of them are already tagged with [bdd](/questions/tagged/bdd) anyway, I've retagged all 7 to just use the [bdd](/questions/tagged/bdd) tag. Since it now has no questions at all, the [behaviour-driven-design](/questions/tagged/behaviour-driven-design) tag will be destroyed in a day or two by our automated tag cleanup.

[image: burninated]

---

The tag wikis for [bdd](/questions/tagged/bdd) and [behaviour-driven-design](/questions/tagged/behaviour-driven-design):

> [image: BDD stands for Behavior Driven Development. It is related to, and derived from, TDD (Test Driven Development) and ATDD (Acceptance Test Driven Development), and differs in its language and vocabulary, preferring example, scenario or specification to test.]
>
> [image: BDD stands for Behavior Driven Development. It is related to, and derived from, TDD (Test Driven Development) and ATDD (Acceptance Test Driven Development). BDD differs from them in its choice language and vocabulary. It prefers 'example', 'scenario' or 'specification' to 'test'.]

Can you tell which is which? Neither can I!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Jonathan. Let's wait to see what the moderators say.

Comment: That's because the OP suggested editing the second one to have the same wiki as the first, and it was approved even though it used the word "development" instead of "design" and spelled Behavior in the American way, not in the way the tag was spelled. (Not that I think they're actually different things, just that the wiki evidence isn't particularly compelling :) )

Comment: @Wooble Aha, I see now.